# C# documentation XML: Is there a DTD?

Tags: c#

I'm writing XML documentation for a couple of C# projects. I want to be able to parse the file that comes out into HTML suitable for posting on GitHub Pages. I've got a pretty good handle on the parsing process itself, but I need an idea of *all* the elements that might show up in documentation.

I thought that a DTD might be the best resource for this, does that exist? Or is this all completely free-form?

I realize there are a few tools that already exist to do this, but I want finer control over the process and honestly it's good practice anyway.

Comment: What is a DTD in this context? Could you clarify what you are asking for?

Comment: MSDN has a [pretty good list of the available elements](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b2s063f7.aspx). Why would a DTD help?

Comment: I could just be confused. Are there any rules for what tags can appear in comments? Is the output file usually validated against something? It's made of XML, so I'd assume a document type definition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

XML validation is a product of some sort of application. The documentation comments in C# are just XML. It is the application that you parse/process the comments with that determines if there are any rules for what elements are allowed. There are [multiple applications](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48381/generating-documentation-from-c-sharp-xml-comments) that can convert XML documentation comments into documentation, and you could even build your own if needed.

As mentioned, MSDN has a [list of available elements](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b2s063f7.aspx). These are standardized across most parsers. If you need to add additional elements it is fine if you have a parser that can handle them. You could even add an XSD or DTD if you wanted for that application, if supported.

Comment: You're right. I missed [this part](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5ast78ax.aspx):

"The compiler will process any tag that is valid XML."

I'll just make it as flexible as possible. Thank you.